# Python: "long int too large to convert to float" when checking (really big) prime numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, int, precision, primes

I have tried to implement the first is_prime-function from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17298131/6208280

```
# for large numbers, xrange will throw an error.
# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
# to get over this:

def mrange(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step

# benchmarked on an old single-core system with 2GB RAM.

from math import sqrt

def is_prime(num):
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if (num < 2) or (num % 2 == 0):
        return False
    return all(num % i for i in mrange(3, int(sqrt(num)) + 1, 2))
```

Yet I have a little probleme while testing high numbers.

For really high numbers, I get an overflow error: `long int too large to convert to float`

I checked the max for float:

```
sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

for `is_prime(10**308)` everything works fine... but for example with `is_prime(10**309)` there will be this overflow error (because of the float max?).

Does that mean 1.7976931348623157e+308 is the limit for this kind of is_prime()-function or is there any solution to check higher numbers with the is_prime()-function?

In my mind such solutions as "use decimal" will not really solve the problem, because of the lack of precision a prime number checking function will need?

Comment: It means that `(sys.float_info.max - ϵ) ** 2` is the limit, as you're calling `sqrt(num)`.  There are "integer square root algorithms" that side step any use of floats, maybe like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391420/736937)

Comment: Have you thought about how many operations would be required to check that a 308-digit number is prime, and how long that would take? Your function is already going to be way too slow for 20-digit numbers, let alone 300-digit ones.

Answer (score 3):

If the only reason you need floats is to be able to do `int(sqrt(num))`, you can find a reasonably efficient `intsqrt` function and use that instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807), and the blog post linked from the accepted answer, for some ideas.

---

Or you can just change your code so that it doesn't need to `sqrt` at all. For example, instead of a range that ends with `int(sqrt(num))+1`, you can use a [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) that tests `lambda i: i*i <= num`. Or, since you've already got that `mrange` function:

```
def sqrmrange(start, sqrstop):
    while start*start < sqrstop:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Or, if you don't need it to be a one-liner, you can probably write something less abstract (and maybe more efficient?) than either of those. (But really, any `intsqrt` could well be faster than the best possible `**2` test, because you only have to do the `intsqrt` once, at the start of the loop, rather than every time through the loop.)

---

Or, if you really want to keep things structured this way, you can just use `decimal`. You say:

> In my mind such solutions as "use decimal" will not really solve the problem, because of the lack of precision a prime number checking function will need?

But that's not right. Using `float` means you're inherently limited to 52 bits of precision, which if a problem long before you get to overflowing. Using `decimal` means you get as many digits of precision as you ask for—and even the default 30 digits is already much more than 52 bits. For example:

```
>>> float(10**20) == float(10**20)+1
True
>>> Decimal(10**20) == Decimal(10**20)+1
False
```

(In fact, since you're constructing that `Decimal` from a huge `int`, it's going to automatically expand to track as many digits as are needed for the `int`… but you do still need to set the precision before calling `sqrt` on it.)

It can be complicated to programmatically calculate and set the desired precision for an operation, but in this case, it's pretty simple. The bigger problem is that really big `Decimals` are a lot slower than really big ints.